# Ensemble learning timeseries: Standard K-fold cross-validation ok for final step?

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation

I have used 5 different classification models to predict future price direction (up or down) using caret's timeslice for each model type.

I now want to put all the models predicted probabilities together into a decision tree (XGboost, etc) to enhance my predictions. Must I also use the timeslice rolling cross validation for the decision tree, or is the standard k-fold cross validation okay for this final step?

Answer (score 1):

Stay with rolling-window/timeslice cross validation.

Whether rolling-window cross validation or "normal" cross validation is needed depends on the nature of your data, not on the model (validation/verification procedures that compare prediction with reference outcome *never* depend on the model - they treat the model as black box).

Once you found that rolling window is what is needed to achieve statistically independent splitting, that is what you need to do for *all* cross validation steps during your whole modeling process.